# python 3 open excel files in a directory

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to work on a script that will open an excel file in a folder. update the workbook with openpyxl. Save the file.  Open the next file in the directory and do the same.

I'm trying this without success:

```
import os.glob
folder_path = 'G:\\My Drive\\Reports\\'
for filename in glob.glob(os,path.join(folder_path, '*.xlsm')):
    with open(filename, 'r' as f:
        text = f.read()
        print (filename)
        print (len(text))
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Font, Border, Side, Alignment
wb=Workbook()
ws=wb.active
Update cells

wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren on the 4th line...

Comment: What is this? `Update cells`

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have to do it inside `for`-loop but you do it after leaving `for`-loop. BTW: put all imports at the beginning to make it more readable.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `open()`, `read()` if you want to work with excel files. `open()`, `read()` is useful for text files (or similar) but `Excel` uses more complex file and it needs specilized function to read file - and you should use `openpyxl` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong indentations. You have to do it inside `for`-loop.

And you have to use function from module `openpyxl` to open and read Excel file.

Functions `open()`, `read()` are useful to read text files (or similar) or to read raw data but `Excel` uses more complex files (ie. it can use `.zip` file with many  `.xml` files) and you need module like `openpyxl` to read it.

```
import os
import glob
import openpyxl

folder_path = 'G:\\My Drive\\Reports\\'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.xlsm')):

    print(filename)

    wb = openpyxl.open(filename)
    ws = wb.active

    #Update cells
    print('old value:', ws['A1'].value)
    ws['A1'] = 'Hello World'
    print('new value:', ws['A1'].value)

    wb.save(filename)
```

---

**BTW:** always put all imports at the beginning to make code more readable.

See also: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you.  The PEP 8 -- Style guide for Python code is very helpful.